# How see if a Play Store app is available for the "Rest of the World" region?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm a software researcher looking at app availability across different countries, and I'd like to see if an app is available in the "Rest of the World" region. The `gl` parameter seems to be used to select the country. You can, for example, see that TikTok is available in [France here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhiliaoapp.musically&gl=fr) and that it's not available in [China here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhiliaoapp.musically&gl=cn)

What is the correct `gl` parameter to see the version for the Rest of the World region?

If you give a presumably invalid value like `gl=zz` you do get served a page, I'm not clear how the store chooses which version to show you in that case, which means if you try one of the country codes for a country in the Rest of the World region, it's not clear if you're seeing the rest of the world page, or some default

Comment: Are you just looking at Play Store website or on device Play Store which may use additional restriction factors, see: [Cannot see, buy, or download apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37642/3573)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, I just want to see the website for that region